# Copy and Paste between two fields in Selenium(Java)

Tags: java, selenium, copy-paste

Environment: Firefox and coded in Java(in Eclipse). Framework: Selenium WebDriver

What this code does is click on a calendar button to select a value(date/time) for field 1. Then it selects everything in field 1 using(Command-A) and copies the input using(Command-C). Then it will paste the value into field 2. 
Expectation: Read above.
Actual: Will paste the last thing on my clipboard and not what's in field 1.

Notes: I can manipulate these results by manually copying the values in field 1 and then when I rerun my test it will paste it. So it will basically paste the last thing I've manually copied into my clipboard.

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-trigger")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[3]/button[1]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[3]/button[2]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='entryTime']")).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + "a",(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + "c"));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='expirationTime']")).clear();

    WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='expirationTime']"));
    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.contextClick(element2).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy as given below.

```
  Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
  clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='entryTime']")).getAttribute("value")), null);
```